# Are ADFS 2.0 / SAML Tokens in ASP.NET sticky?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, saml, adfs, identityserver3

We are running an ASP.NET 4.6 application with ADFS 2.0. The configuration of the web.config ADFS part was created via FedUtil.exe.

We now have the problem that a second instance of the web application still thinks that the user is not authenticated.

- auth on server 1 works only on server 1
- auth on server 2 works only on server 2

but..

- auth on server 1 cannot be recognized on server 2 and vise versa

In our scenario only a sticky session would work in a load balanced environment. I think it is because of the SessionModule which is required:

```
    <modules>
        <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
```

Am I right that the SessionModule stores any data of the auth* into a session, so a shared session would not be possible and we are forced to use sticky sessions?

Would IdentityServer3 or IdentityServer4 solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be that the Microsoft.Identity does not provide SAML Tokens without Sticky Sessions: https://leastprivilege.com/2012/07/12/machinekey-based-session-protection-for-wif/